# How to get Pin to work in UV maps once you have joined a mesh?

Tags: uv, linked-data

I have created a new file for testing purpose. Create Monkey, seperate lose parts from the mesh (the eyes) copy uv maps, join everything together. Now both eyes share the same space in the uv map. But now if I pin those islands and hit U to unwrap, the vertices will end up like a wierd unusable spaghetti mess. Already tried to clear everything with Object -> Relations -> Make Single User but nope.
Is there a way to get pin to work?

[image]

[image]

https://pasteall.org/blend/969eb6ce7b6742438b221674fcb0d3ab

Comment: Isn't the problem in copying the UVs, not pinning or unwrapping? Indexes of the vertices don't match, so the UV quads are chaotic.

Comment: Open these images in two tabs and switch between them with CTRL+Page Down/Page Up to compare indices: https://i.imgur.com/401W7pZ.png https://i.imgur.com/hjN3CkW.png

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady ah thanks, that explains it. Did not know about the indices in overlay, nice feature to know about. (in case someone is wondering, you have to activate | Preference, Interface, developer extra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even before applying subdivision, you can see a problem by adding a texture to your Susanne:

[image]

Clearly the eye to which you copied UV is scrambled, because its vertex order is not the same as in the other eye, so the UV no longer fits.

The simplest solution to your problem is to just mirror the eye:

[image]

In cases where the objects aren't exactly the same, you can align one to the other as much as you can, then do the <kbd>Cltr</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> Transfer Mesh Data and select UV, then clear the transformations of the object you moved to return it to the place it was before.